# Error occurred prerendering page "/api-doc" - Next 13 (npm)

Tags: next.js, swagger-ui, next.js13

I am attempting to add Swagger docs through next-swagger-doc. The endpoint documentation renders & works correctly locally but fails to build inside a Docker container or in Vercel deployment. The code is an exact replica of "Usage Case 1" from the documentation: https://github.com/jellydn/next-swagger-doc

When rendering the Swagger docs page (which was working as intended), I encountered the following warning:

```
- warn ./node_modules/swagger-jsdoc/src/utils.js
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/swagger-jsdoc/src/utils.js
./node_modules/swagger-jsdoc/src/specification.js
./node_modules/swagger-jsdoc/src/lib.js
./node_modules/swagger-jsdoc/index.js
./node_modules/next-swagger-doc/dist/index.js
./swagger.ts
./app/api-doc/page.tsx
```

I have a couple of questions:

1. Does the choice between Node and Yarn matter? We are using Node 16.
2. How can I resolve this TypeError?

Here's the full log:

```
41.42 TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
41.42     at /app/.next/server/chunks/334.js:28855:816054
41.42     at /app/.next/server/chunks/334.js:28855:1386511
41.42     at /app/.next/server/chunks/334.js:28855:1386527
41.42     at webpackUniversalModuleDefinition (/app/.next/server/chunks/334.js:28855:70)
41.42     at Object.20404 (/app/.next/server/chunks/334.js:28855:76)
41.42     at __webpack_require__ (/app/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:25:43)
41.42     at Object.93670 (/app/.next/server/chunks/334.js:34301:69)
41.42     at __webpack_require__ (/app/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:25:43)
41.42     at Module.6054 (/app/.next/server/app/api-doc/page.js:336:74)
41.42     at __webpack_require__ (/app/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:25:43)
41.42 
41.42 Error occurred prerendering page "/api-doc". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
41.42 TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
41.42     at /app/.next/server/chunks/334.js:28855:816054
41.42     at /app/.next/server/chunks/334.js:28855:1386511
41.42     at /app/.next/server/chunks/334.js:28855:1386527
41.42     at webpackUniversalModuleDefinition (/app/.next/server/chunks/334.js:28855:70)
41.42     at Object.20404 (/app/.next/server/chunks/334.js:28855:76)
41.42     at __webpack_require__ (/app/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:25:43)
41.42     at Object.93670 (/app/.next/server/chunks/334.js:34301:69)
41.42     at __webpack_require__ (/app/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:25:43)
41.42     at Module.6054 (/app/.next/server/app/api-doc/page.js:336:74)
41.42     at __webpack_require__ (/app/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:25:43)
41.42 - info Generating static pages (24/33)
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the code below to my `next.config.js` file fixed the issue for me

```js
  webpack: config => {
    config.ignoreWarnings = [
      {module: /node_modules\/swagger-jsdoc\/src\/utils\.js/},
      {file: /node_modules\/swagger-jsdoc\/src\/index\.js/},
    ];

    return config;
  },
```